# Using React Virtualized Select without node backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, umd, react-select, react-virtualized

I wanted to use the [React Virtualized Select](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select) to show almost around 1 million records in a select dropdown. I have already created the project based on flask and angularjs. I wasn't able to find any resources for such a dropdown through angularjs, so I came to the decision to use react.js with angular.js to get this select dropdown.

Coming to my question, please find below the code I have tried till now. Since I am not using nodeJS I cant use "require" or "include" which play a major role for these dropdowns, but luckily they had provided UMD javascript files for "react-virtualized-select", so I included these scripts in the end of the HTML body, but when I run the code I am getting the error in the console as

> embedded:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: VirtualizedSelect is not defined

Could someone tell me if I am implementing react the proper way or is there something I am understand wrong about UMD files? Thanks in advance.

Update: I have created a JS Fiddle highlighting the issue, I have also made some changes to the code based on comments from SO.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Hello React!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-  select/1.0.0-beta14/react-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./VirtualizedSelect.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='root'/>
<Application/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/classnames/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize/dist/react-input-autosize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-select/1.0.0-beta14/react-select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-virtualized/7.0.0/react-virtualized.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./react-virtualized-select.js"></script>//UMD File from GITHUB

<script type="text/babel">
  class Application extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {}
    }

    render () {
      const options = [
          { label: 'one', value: 'One' },
          { label: 'two', value: 'Two' },
          { label: 'three', value: 'Three' },
          { label: 'four', value: 'Four' },
          { label: 'five', value: 'Five' },
          { label: 'six', value: 'Six', disabled: true }
        // And so on...
      ]

      return (
        <VirtualizedSelect options={options} onChange={(selectValue) => this.setState({ selectValue })} value={this.state.selectValue}/>
      )
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Application/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to help you on this since I can't test the code.
But it's probably because you don't specify the 'package' for `VirtualizedSelect`. 
Try `<Foo.VirtualizedSelect ...`
You can find Foo in the .js file, it looks something like `exports.Foo`

If I for example want to use `VirtualScroll` from `react-virtualized.min.js` I would need to write `<ReactVirtualized.VirtualScroll ..` since the file states `exports.ReactVirtualized`. If I dont I get the same error as you got.

---

Edit:

This is not the best solution but it's a solution. Since the 'package' is exported as `react-virtualized-select` and you're not allowed minuses in javascript names you can "import" it as follows:

```
const VirtualizedSelect = window["react-virtualized-select"].default;
```

and use it as you did at first:

```
<VirtualizedSelect options={options} ... />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I tried what you told but now I am getting the error "react-with-addons.min.js:16 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[…undefined&args[]=%20Check%20the%20render%20method%20of%20%60Application%60. for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."

I have also created a JS FIddle with the complete code for your reference,
https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/q8om2be6/1/

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/0p2j0wc6/](https://jsfiddle.net/0p2j0wc6/) here is a jsfiddle with the code working.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the solution I was looking for :)